# Сохранить данные компьютера сделавшего запрос на сервер Flask и через некоторое время обратиться к нему с сервера

Tags: python-3.x, requests, flask

Есть сервер на Flask, на него приходит запрос, и из этого запроса мне нужно получить данные клиента, чтобы потом по ним обратиться к клиенту. Это должно быть не в качестве ответа в POST-запрос, а в виде рассылки.
Например: к серверу приходят запросы с клиентов, сервер запоминает их ip (или что-то вроде того) и потом сам обращается к ним. И клиент и сервер пишу я, могу менять с обоих сторон код.

Сервер на Flask, клиент использует requests.

На всякий случай, вот пример:

Сервер:

```
import flask, os, json
from flask import app, request

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


class Server():
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}  

    def add_User(self, id, IP):
        self.clients[id] = IP  # Здесь нужно что-то, благодаря чему я смогу обратиться к клиенту 
        return {'code': 200, 'error': ''}
    
    def post_tu_clients(self):
        for i in self.clients.keys():
            continue  # Рассылка клиентам


serv = Server()


@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def addUser():
    data = request.get_json()
    if type(data) == str:
        data = json.loads(data)
    resp = serv.add_User(data['id'], IP)
    return json.dumps(resp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5050))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Клиент

```
import json
from const import *
from requests import Session
from Entitys.Player import Player


class API:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()

    def in_server_init(self, player: Player):
        data = {
            'id': player.id,
        }
        resp = self.session.post(url=URL + '/add', json=json.dumps(data)).json()
        if resp['code'] != 200:
            print('Что то не так в addUser', resp['error'])
            return
```